Euler characteristic of Hirzebruch surface
Let $\mathbb{F}_n = \mathbb{P}(\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O}(n))$ be the $n$th Hirzebruch surface.
How do I compute the holomorphic Euler characterisic of $\mathbb{F}_n$ in terms of $n$?
Can I also compute the Chern classes?

The dimensions of the cohomology groups of $O_X$ are birational invariants of smooth projective varieties, so the holomorphic Euler characteristic of $\mathbb F_n$ is the same as that of $\mathbb P^2$, namely 1. The first Chern class $c_1(T_X)$ is the same as the anticanonical class, which is $(2+n)f+2e$ where $f$ is the class of a fibre and $e$ is the unique negative section. The second Chern class $c_2(T_X)$ is the topological Euler characteristic, which equals 4 for all $n$.

@LazzaroCampeotti that looks like an answer to me - please consider recording it as such below.

Why is the first Chern class the same as the anticanonical class? And how do you compute that?

c_1 of a vector bundle is c_1 of its determinant (a consequence of the Whitney axioms and the splitting principle)

The dimensions of the cohomology groups of $O_X$
are birational invariants of smooth projective varieties $X$, so the holomorphic Euler characteristic of $\mathbb F_n$ is the same as that of $\mathbb P^2$, namely 1.
The first Chern class $c_1(\mathbb F_n)$ is the same as the anticanonical class; this follows (for any smooth variety) by a standard splitting priniciple argument, since the anticanonical bundle is the determinant of the tangent bundle. Using for example two applications of the adjunction formula, one finds that the anticanonical bundle is $(2+n)f+2e$, where $f$ is the class of a fibre and $e$ is the unique negative section.
Finally, the second Chern class $c_2(\mathbb F_n)$ is (the class of a point times) the topological Euler characteristic, which equals 4 for all $n$.
Addendum: Let me give a little more detail on calculating the anticanonical class, as requested by the OP.
I take as given the existence of a unique curve $E$ on $\mathbb F_n$ which is a section of the projection and such that $E^2=-n$, and that $\operatorname{Pic}(\mathbb F_n)$ is freely generated by $e$ and $f$, meaning the class of $E$ and the class of any fibre $F$, respectively. Note that $f^2=0$ since $F$ is a fibre, and $e \cdot f=1$ since $E$ is a section.
Given the above, there are integers $a$ and $b$ such that $K_\mathbb F = af+be.$ We use adjunction to find $a$ and $b$.
First apply adjunction to $F$ to get $K_F = (K_\mathbb F + F)_{|F}$. Using that $F$ is a copy of $\mathbb P^1$ and the information above, we deduce $b=-2$.
Next apply adjunction to $E$: we get
\begin{align*}
K_E&=(K_\mathbb F +E)_{|E}\\
&=(aF-E)_{|E}\\
&=a+n.
\end{align*}
Since $E$ is also a copy of $\mathbb P^1$ this gives $a=-n-2$. So we conclude that $K_\mathbb F = (-n-2)f-2e$ as claimed.

Sorry, I'm still confused about the adjunction formula and the canonical. Could you clarify on that? Which embeddings are you using? That is, how exactly do you apply the adjunction formula?
